# Finding most efficient path between two nodes in an interval graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, networkx

I have interval data:

```
A = (0,50)
B = (20,500)
C = (80,420)
....
```

And realized that there's an associated graph with this data, [the interval graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph)

[image]

I'd like to find the most efficient path to go from A to G (assume I know all of the positive vertex weights, wa, wb, wc...).  I need to start at A and go to G, so the minimum spanning tree must be bound between these points.  One of the constraints in our application is that the interval starting at A and ending at G must be covered in full (no gaps).  I'm looking at [networkX's minspanning tree method](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.mst.minimum_spanning_tree.html#networkx.algorithms.mst.minimum_spanning_tree), and don't understand how to specify that A and G must be the start and endpoints.

Some other questions that come to mind are:

1. Since this problem is NP-hard, should I even bother looking for a min-spanning tree if the number of nodes is high?  How many nodes would be too many?
2. Notice that interval F has a unique region.  In other words, to completely cover the interval A-G, one HAS to go through F.  Therefore, my minimum spanning tree probably should only connect A-F, not A-G.  Is there a standard way, given a larger graph, to find all of the subgraphs whose intervals contain no unique patches?  In other words, since all paths have to pass through F to get to G, A-F is the min spanning path of interest, not A-G.  How does one reduce a graph in such a way without inspecting it manually?
3. Becasue I have to go from A-G, I would never go backwards or take a cyclic path.  For example, I'd never go A-B-A.  Do spanning trees incorporate this?  And does this make my graph directed?  Consider point C: from C one could go to D, E, or F, but never back to A (for our use case).  What does this mean in regard to directionality of the graph?

Sorry for novice Q's, new to most of this.

Comment: It doesn't seem a min spanning tree problem to me. It seems a simple shortest path problem. Also, minimum spanning tree isn't NP-hard. It is in P. And a spanning tree never have cycles, by the very definition of a tree.

Comment: Thanks Juan.  It's probably obvious that I'm new at this.  When you say shortest path, does that take into account node weights.  IE the C node/interval covers the most distance, but depending on other constraints, may have a bad cost, so the path A, D, F is actually preferred.  Any idea where I can learn more about this subset of problems?

Comment: Yes, Dijkstra's algorithm (as well as several other shortest path algorithms) takes the edges' weight in consideration. In your case the weight is defined by the node, but you can easily adapt by setting the edge's weight using the weight of the node on which it arrives.

Comment: FWIW, you shouldn't implement dijkstra's algorithm yourself.  It's already in place in networkx (I give the code specific to your case in my answer).

Comment: Also, you should be aware that the minimum spanning tree isn't guaranteed to have the shortest path between two nodes.  Consider this simple observation: if you find a minimal spanning tree of anything that had a cycle, there must be an edge between some `x` and `y` which has been removed.  Then clearly the minimal spanning tree does not have the shortest path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must go from A to G in an efficient way, you aren't looking for a minimum spanning tree algorithm. A simple shortest path algorithm is enough. You just have to adapt you graph to put the weights in the edges instead of the nodes. But it's just a matter of setting the node's weight to the incoming edge.

Also, both shortest path and minimum spanning tree problems aren't NP-hard. There are known polynomial algorithms for all these problems. In special, shortest path can be solved by [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) (if your graph doesn't have negative edges, which seems to be true) and minimum spanning tree can be solved by [Prim's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) or [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm).

And finally, any tree, by definition doesn't have cycles.

Comment: So I don't have an interval graph per-se, I have a tree?

Comment: No, you do have an interval graph, but if you compute its minimum spanning tree, it is guaranteed to have no cycles, because a tree, by definition, is an acyclic connected graph.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks!  In regard to "setting the node's weight to the incoming edge", so the edge A-C.  Would it have the weight of node A?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, you can choose either A' or C's weight. It just have to be consistent across the graph.

Comment: @AdamHughes Sorry, edit: there was an error, minimum spanning tree can be solved using Prim or Kruskal, not Edmonds-Karp. The latter is for maximum flow.

Comment: It's worth giving the actual networkx algorithm (I've added an answer, but it would be good to point to the fact that these algorithms are already built in to networkx).  In this case it's `dijkstra_path`.  http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html

Comment: Looking at this algorithm visually (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), I'm worried about a certain case.  In the wiki graphic for Dijkstra, what if the shortest path was 1, 2, 4, 5.  Maybe the cost of 2,4,5 is super low, but 1,2 is not low.  It looks like dijkstra's path would never pick this because 1,2 was not the first edge chosen.  Is this just a limitation of the algorithm?  Obviously one can't examine all paths, but is there a way to tell it to look at the first few downstream steps before choosing it's first node?  AKA, look ahead a few nodes each time.

Comment: This won't be a problem.  The algorithm takes care of it.  It basically keeps track of paths that it knows are shortest paths, and paths that might be shortest paths separately.  If the shortest path to node 2 is shorter than any other path to node 5, then it will still have the paths to 5 in the "possible, but not sure" category when it knows it's found the shortest path to 2.  Once it's got the shortest path to 2, it will manage to find the path to 4 while it's still unsure about whether it's got the shortest to 5, and then it will realize that the path through 2-4 to 5 is shortest.

Comment: Hey Joel, I posted this question separately before I saw this comment:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349716/dijkstras-algorithm-with-back-tracking

Sorry, I mixed up this comment and your other comment on the other answer.  I can delete that thread, but you might want to post this as an answer; it could be useful to others.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in another answer, Dijkstra's algorithm is the solution.  What wasn't mentioned is how to implement that solution in networkx.  Here it is.  Simple as this:

```
import networkx as nx
my_graph = nx.Graph()
my_graph.add_edges_from([('A','B'),('B','C'),('A','C'),('C','D'),('A','D'),('C','E'),('D','E'),('D','F'),('F','G')]) 
#graph is now defined.

shortestpath = nx.dijkstra_path(my_graph, 'A', 'G') #optional weight argument here.
shortestpath
> ['A', 'D', 'F', 'G']
```

In general, more documentation on how to do the shortest path algorithms (and there are many variations thereof) in networkx is [here](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html).

Note if you have weights on nodes and you want to minimize the sum of the nodes in the path, what you do is place weights on the edges so that the weight of (`u`, `v`) is `(w[u]+w[v])/2`.

Then run `nx.dijkstra_path` with the optional argument telling networkx where to find the weight of the edges.  The weight of the entire path will equal the sum of the intermediate weights, plus half the values of the end nodes.  You can then correct for the end node weights.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I appreciate you sharing; it will save me much time.  I now understand the difference between shortest path and spanning tree, so thanks to everyone for clarifying this.

Comment: Is there a way to construct the graph from interval ranges like my data?  IE, the overlap in my dataset should automatically imply connectivity in the graph construction.

Comment: There will be ways.  I can think of some, but others may have better ideas (and it'll take more room than a comment can do).  You may pose it as another question.