# Dijkstra's algorithm with back tracking?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, dijkstra

In a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333756/finding-most-efficient-path-between-two-nodes-in-an-interval-graph/28333937#28333937), it was suggested that I impliment Dijkstra's algorithm for finding the shortest path on a graph.  Looking at this .gif of the algorithm from wikipedia:

[image]

What if the path 1,3,6,5 turned out to be very low cost?  For example, the weight on 3-6 was 1, and the weight on 6-5 was 2?  Dijkstra's algorithm would not consider this path because it only looks one step ahead; it skipped node 3.

Is it acceptable to specify a parameter that makes the algorithm look 2,3,4...n steps ahead before choosing each node?  I realize that this could potentially blow up computational time, but as long as the nodes aren't very dense (ie not more than 3 or 4 connections per node), this could provide a decent tradeoff between performance and optimal solution for our specific dataset.

Does anyone have strong feelings about this?  And is such a shortest-path algorithm with this adjustable parameter likely to be in graph packages or not?

Comment: djikstra is often implemented as dynamic programming as far as I am aware it is guaranteed to find the lowest cost path between two nodes(assuming no negative cost edges).  other than that Im not really sure what you are asking

Comment: I didn't understand your question. In the example given, the shortest path between 1 and 5 is already 1, 3, 6, 5. And the algorithm finds exactly that. See how it marks the distance to 5 as 20? It is 1-3 (9), 3-6 (2), 6-5 (9).

Comment: The most surefire way to properly understand an algorithm is working through a proof of correctness, assuming you have the mathematical education to follow such a proof. Asking yourself why it should always work indicates an interest in the matter, and Dijkstra's algorithm is not all that difficult to prove. Give it a go! Nothing like formalism to put your mind at ease with algorithms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dijkstra algorithm always finds the shortest path (in graphs without negative edges) and never backtracks. It is easy to reason about it.

#### Always choosing the minimum

Think about a node and its edges (it's just part of a larger graph):

```
    6   _ 3
    |  /
  14| /9
    |/
    1-------2
        7
```

Dijkstra's algorithm will begin choosing the edge `1-2 (7)`. I does so because it is the minimum it has seen so far. It then sets the value of the shortest path to `2` as `7`. It will never change this value again, because any other path from `1` to `2` must be larger (as it must start with one of the edges `1-3 (9)` or `1-6 (14)`).

#### Consider the known nodes as a single node

One way to reason about what comes next is to pretend the algorithm merges "known" nodes into a single one. In the example, as soon as the shortest path to `2` is chosen, it merges `1` and `2` as a single logical node. All edges going out of `2` are increased by `7` (the shortest path to `2`). The next step is to choose the smallest edge outgoing from the "supernode". The reasoning then is the same as the first step:

```
    6   _ 3
    |  /
  14| /9
    |/
   1,2-------4
        22
```

In this state, the next chosen edge is `1,2-3 (9)`. The shortest path to `3` is set as `9` and all of its edges are now considered to choose the next minimum (please note how the edges to `6` and `4` have been updated):

```
    6
    |
  11|
    |
   1,2,3----4
         20
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  I also found this video informative: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdmfOwyQlcI

Answer (score 3):

It would not skip node 3. It would do this:

Start from node `1`, update distances to neighbours:

```
d[2] = 7
d[3] = 9
d[6] = 14
```

Pick the next unvisited node with distance from source minimum, in this case node `2` and update the distances to its neighbors:

```
d[3] = min(d[3], d[2] + c(2, 3))
     = min(9, 7 + 10)
     = 9

d[4] = min(d[4], d[2] + c(2,4))
     = min(inf, 7 + 15)
     = 22
```

Then it will pick `3`: update the distances to its neighbours:

```
d[6] = min(d[6], d[3] + c(3, 6))
     = min(14, 9 + 1)
     = 10
```

Then pick the next unvisited node with distance `d` minimum and do the same. Stop when you pick your destination node.

There is no need to do what you suggest, the algorithm will work just fine as long as your edge weights are positive.

Comment: dynamic programming gets  +1 from me always :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley - thanks, but Dijkstra's algorithm is not a DP algorithm, it's a greedy algorithm :). However, it's proven to work as long as the edge costs are positive.

Comment: Im sure there are non-DP ways to implement it ... however in my book its always DP where it successively builds the path:P (its also the example my teacher used when teaching about DP :P )

Comment: Greedy algorithms are a subset of DP algorithms.

Comment: *Head Explodes* (are you sure about that @Zaphod  , Ill believe it ... but  I hadnt ever really heard that before or thought about it)

Comment: IVlad, thanks.  So you are saying it already kind of "looks ahead".  Does it do this indefinitely?  IE it passes through the entire network and assigns this scoring to each node in one pass?

Comment: @AdamHughes - no, I wouldn't say it looks ahead. Think of it as coming back to each node and considering it, ensuring that it finds the absolute minimum path in the end. It doesn't assign this scoring to each node in one pass, but it will have assigned this scoring to each node at the end of the algorithm.

Comment: I'll try to read about the algorithm more to understand, but how far will it go ahead before coming back?  It seems like such behavior would lead to exponential time?  I must be thinking about this wrong

Comment: @AdamHughes - it's hard to say how long, it depends on the edge weights. It won't lead to exponential time because each node will only be picked once.

Comment: @JoranBeasley - it depends on the actual implementation used. The easiest one is indeed `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @AdamHughes I think you might have a misconception of the idea behind the algorithm. Dijkstra isn't about looking ahead and then backtracking if a better way is found. Rather it calculates the shortest distance to the start point for EVERY node (and thus incidentally the shortest distance to the target point) in a systematic scheme. Beginning from the start point the explored/finished nodes spread out in a kind of wave-like ripple.

Comment: Thanks PeterE.  Yes, I did have this misunderstanding.  The answers provided here plus this video have cleared it up for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdmfOwyQlcI