# Shortest path with a maximum number of vertices

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I want to find the shortest path between two vertices with an additional constraint : max **n** vertices can be visited. The graph is directed, connected, non negative weights and may contain cycles.

Example:

[image]

1. Shortest path **0->2** with **n = 2** is **18**
2. Shortest path **0->3** with **n = 3** is **22**
3. Shortest path **0->3** with **n = 4** is **9**

So far I've implemented Djikstras algorithm to get the simple shortest path, and my idea was to keep a counter of the current vertices visited, if it exceeds **n** it takes one or more steps back and tries with another path.. but as far as I know Djikstras can't be used for backtracking as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349716/dijkstras-algorithm-with-back-tracking).

Another idea is somehow to store every path between every node in a table. But I'm not really sure how Djikstra can discover the path **0->2 with weight 18** since it is not really a shortest path...

Does anyone have any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Comment: what about counting how many vertices visited like you mentioned but instead of backtracking apply it as part of the weight? the weight should increase for every step. you'll have to normalize it somehow though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divided each vertices into `n` vertices, that is, for vertices `u`, we create `n` vertices expressed as `(u, 1) ... (u, n)`, the second number shows the number of steps to this vertices. For each edge from u to v, we create an edge from (u, i) to (v, i+1) where `1<=i<=n-1` in new graph. Now if you want to calculate the shortest path between u and v with n, just do Dijkstra from (u, 1), then your answer is `min(result (v, i) | 1<=i<=n)`

The total number of vertices can be n*n, so the complexity is about `O(n^2*log(n^2))`

Answer (score 2):

Let COST_TO(v,n) be the total weight of the minimum path to vertex v with n edges or less.

When n=0, the answer is easy:

for all v, COST_T(v,0) = 0 if v is the source vertex and infinity otherwise

For n>0, COST_TO(v,n) is the minimum of COST_TO(v,n-1) and all COST_TO(w,n-1)+WEIGHT(w,v), where there is an edge from w to v

so, for n = 0 to N, keep track of all the vertices with COST_(v,n) < infinity along with their costs, and calculate the costs for n from the values for n-1.

At the same time you can keep track of the minimum weight path to each v -- every time you update the cost to v with the edge rule, the new path to v is the path to w plus that edge. A reverse-singly-linked list is handy for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a bfs and check the number of vertices against the max.  Save the best of the ones that fulfill the constraints.

Heres a video about it
https://youtu.be/TvHV3PB8ANs

Nist.gov has some algos as well.

Comment: Video has been deleted. Do you happen to remember the original title? Or have a pointer to another demonstration of the algo?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you want to find the shortest path from the source vertex `S` to a destination vertex `T` consisting of at most `K` edges. I picked `K`, because the `n` in your question is misleading - if you want to find the shortest path visiting at most `n` vertices, where `n` is the total number of vertices, you can just run Dijkstra, because any simple path has at most `n` vertices - I assume that this is not what you want here.

Then, if you want a simple implementation, [Bellman-Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) is a good choice here:

After the `i-th` iteration of the outer loop, the algorithm has computed the shortest path from the source vertex `S` to any other vertex consisting of `at most i edges`, so it consists of at `at most i + 1 vertices`. So in order to solve your problem, run `K - 1` outer loops of Bellman-Ford, and check if the distance to the destination vertex `T` is well defined (is different than infinity), and if it is, you have your result. Otherwise, `T` is not reachable from `S` in visiting `K` or less vertices.

Comment: I don't think the algorithm necessarily works. The linked Wikipedia page says as much: "At each iteration i that the edges are scanned, the algorithm finds all shortest paths of at most length i edges (and possibly some paths longer than i edges)." That could give an erroneous answer If you need a hard constraint at $i$ edges.